# How to determine the current locale's symbol for a decimal point

Tags: flutter, dart, locale, number-formatting

How can I determine the symbol for the decimal separator? The device's current locale should be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use methods of `NumberFormat` class, available in [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) library.

[`NumberFormat.decimalPattern`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.decimalPattern.html) formats a number according to specified locale.

e.g. this is how you can get device locale and format a number.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show NumberFormat;
import 'package:intl/number_symbols_data.dart' show numberFormatSymbols;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

String getCurrentLocale() {
  final locale = ui.window.locale;
  final joined = "${locale.languageCode}_${locale.countryCode}";
  if (numberFormatSymbols.keys.contains(joined)) {
    return joined;
  }
  return locale.languageCode;
}

// ...

String dec = NumberFormat.decimalPattern(getCurrentLocale()).format(1234.567);
print(dec); // prints 1,234.567 for `en_US` locale
```

However, to answer your initial question - here is a function that returns either decimal separator (if found any) or empty string.

```dart
String getDecimalSeparator(String locale) {
  return numberFormatSymbols[locale]?.DECIMAL_SEP ?? "";
}

// ...

print(getDecimalSeparator(getCurrentLocale())); // prints `.` for `en_US` locale.
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I was hoping for something more elegant as all those symbols like the decimal and thousands separator should be stored somewhere in the intl library, right? But anyway, it works!

Comment: @G.Marc you are right, the same `numberFormatSymbols` that we already use in fact contains all formatting constants for specific languages. Please see updated `getDecimalSeparator` method.

Comment: @George great answer. Do you maybe also know the answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613520/how-to-set-the-maximumfractiondigits-in-a-decimalpattern-in-flutter

Comment: getDecimalSeparator doesn't work with Flutter 3

Comment: NumberFormat() contains the information directly (see the other answer below), so most definitely, don't do it this way.

Comment: `DECIMAL_SEP` gives wrong symbol for `ru`, `tr` locales. I use `DECIMAL_PATTERN[5]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to get the decimal separator. Both functions do the same job and they print

```
. // Point (for "en")
, // Comma (for "de")
```

Without `BuildContext`

```dart
String get decimalSeparator {
  final format = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('${window.locale}');
  return format.symbols.DECIMAL_SEP;
}
```

With `BuildContext`

```dart
String decimalSeparator(BuildContext context) {
  final locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
  final format = NumberFormat.decimalPattern('$locale');
  return format.symbols.DECIMAL_SEP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NumberFormat only uses language code to format numbers which is technically correct. However in iOS from settings users can set number format preferences for some languages like English. This can cause a problem for your textfield because decimal separator can be different on the number keyboard. I developed a package to fix that issue. You can use [locale_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/locale_plus) to get decimal and grouping separator as set in device settings. After that you can set the locale of the NumberFormat according to separator characters you got from the plugin.

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer. If the link breaks it's not clear how to use the package.