# How to set the maximumFractionDigits in a decimalPattern in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Based on the user-locale I show decimals, for example:
1234.567 will be in:

- US: 1,234.567
- NL: 1.234,567

Therefor I use:
`NumberFormat.decimalPattern(locale.toString()).format(1234.567)`

That works fine :)

But now I want to set the max-digets.
There is a [maximumFractionDigits](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/maximumFractionDigits.html), but how to apply this one?

This one doesn't work: `NumberFormat.decimalPattern(locale.toString(), maximumFractionDigits: 2).format(1234.567)`

On the **currency** it works like this: `NumberFormat.currency(locale: locale.toString(), decimalDigits: 3).format(1234567)`

Comment: Can you put an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From another question:

```
var forFractions = new NumberFormat();

forFractions.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
forFractions.maximumFractionDigits = 2;

format(num n) => forFractions.format(n);

print(format(15.501234));
```

So, create your format and set the maximumFractionDigits attribute then execute the format.

Comment: Thanks! Of course it should be this way.
Just to add. If you want to add the locale to the number then initialize it like:     `NumberFormat numberFormat =  new NumberFormat.decimalPattern(locale.toString());`